# Print Maximum Frequent Element

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class TestClass {

    private static int maxOccurence(int a[]) {
        int max = 0;
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) {
                if (a[i] == a[j]) {
                    count++;
                    max = Math.max(max, count);
                }
            }
            count = 0;
        }
        return max + 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[] = { 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4 };
        System.out.println(maxOccurence(a));
    }
}
```

This program counts, for each element of an array, the number of times that the element appears; then, it returns the maximum value. In my example, the program prints "5", since element "4" occurs 5 times. How can the element also be printed? In this case, the output of the program would be "4 : 5".

Comment: If you wish to keep the form of your code, replace `max = Math.max(count, max)` with `if(count > max) { max = count; }`. Then you can record `i` and `a[i]` in the same block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java you can write

```
int[] a = {3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4};
Map<Integer, Long> countMap = IntStream.of(a).boxed()
        .collect(groupingBy(i -> i, counting()));
Map.Entry<Integer, Long> first = countMap.entrySet().stream()
                        .sorted(comparing(Map.Entry<Integer, Long>::getValue).reversed())
                        .findFirst().orElseThrow(AssertionError::new);
System.out.println(first.getKey()+":"+first.getValue());
```

This prints

```
4:5
```

Answer (score 0):

[ANSWERED WHEN TAG WAS C#]
It seems to be a nice solution :

```
public static class TestClass
{
    public static void PrintMaxOccurence(int[] a)
    {

        var maxOccurenceGroup = a.ToList().GroupBy(s => s)
            .OrderByDescending(s => s.Count())
            .First();

        Console.WriteLine(maxOccurenceGroup.Key + " occured " + maxOccurenceGroup.Count() + " times.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        var a = new[] { 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4 };
        TestClass.PrintMaxOccurence(a);
    }
}
```

Feel free to ask help if needed.

Comment: Aaron, show me how to use it and explain me why it is better to use it, I didn't find the reason after a bit of googling.

Comment: Ok but I never seen a mention of  Function.identity() in any c# post. Could you give me the namespace of your Funtion Class ? I wonder if this discussion isn't born because of the tag change form C# to Java. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

In C# you have to declare variable as `int[] a;` but not `int a[];`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{    
    int[] a = new[] { 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4 };
    PrintMaxOccurence(a);    
}

private static void PrintMaxOccurence(int[] a)
{    
    var result = (from item in a
            group item by item into x
            orderby x.Count() descending
            select new { Element = x.Key, OccurenceCount = x.Count() }).First();

    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", result.Element, result.OccurenceCount);    
}
```

Comment: It was posted with tag "C#" in the beginning, so I answered the question in that case http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34807096/revisions Thanks for downvote

Comment: I see. That makes sense, weird as it is. Downvote removed.

Answer (score 0):

We can as well solve the problem using hashtable as follows.

```
import java.util.Hashtable;


public class MaxOcurr {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Hashtable<Integer,Integer> table = new Hashtable<Integer, Integer>();

    int maxCount = 0;

    int maxValue = -1;

    int a[] = {1,3,2,5,3,6,8,8,8,6,6,7,5,6,4,5,6,4,6,4,1,3,2,6,9,2};

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

      if (table.containsKey(a[i])) {
      table.put(a[i], table.get(a[i])+1);


      } else {
        table.put(a[i],1);
      }


      if (table.get(a[i]) > maxCount) {
        maxCount = table.get(a[i]);
        maxValue = a[i];
      }
    }

    System.out.println(maxValue +":"+ maxCount);

  }

}
```